# Can we dig multiple values in the same level with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I called an API with a response like this

```
{
   "data": {
       "name": "joe",
       "placeofbirth": "canada",
       "address": [],
   }
}
```

I want to get the value of `name` and `placeofbirth` and put it into a new object, so it will be like this

```
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "placeofbirth": "canada"
}
```

I was trying to use this `response.dig("data", "name", "placeofbirth")` but it return errors. If I only selected one field like this `response.dig("data", "name")` or `response.dig("data", "placeofbirth")` I will get the result. Is it not possible to select multiple values using `dig`? If it is not possible, any other solution to achieve my intended result?

Comment: **"it return errors"** -- That's not really true, is it? It returns `nil`, not an error.

Comment: The problem is , `dig` is only looking for a **single value**. Your code, `response.dig("data", "name", "placeofbirth")`, is looking for a value like: `{ "data" => { "name" => { "birthplace" => "???" } } }`. But since no such nested value exists, it returns `nil`.

Comment: Also, the code you might actually be looking for is: `response.require(:data).permit(:name, :placeholder)` -- as this would return `400 bad request` if no `data` attribute is found, and will [permit](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) those two attributes for any update actions.

Comment: @TomLord: it does return an error, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev technically what is actually posted does not return an error, :) simply becuase `hash["data"] #=> nil`. If the OP had posted the actual JSON String e.g. `"{\"data\":{\"name\":\"joe\",\"placeofbirth\":\"canada\",\"address\":[]}}"` and then explained that this JSON was parsed or if the correct keys (for the `Hash` posted) were used then yes it would `TypeError` e.g. `JSON.parse(posted_hash.to_json).dig("data", "name", "placeofbirth")` or `posted_hash.dig(:data,:name,:placeofbirth)` both would return `TypeError (String does not have a #dig method)`

Comment: Although the new object would not look like the desired result either way because that is not the way a `String` keyed `Hash` or a `Symbol` keyed `Hash` would inspect

Comment: @engineersmnky: you assume that that object is a ruby hash with symbol keys, but there's no strong evidence to support this. On the contrary, the question states that it is "a response from API", which, to me, implies JSON, which doesn't have symbol keys.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I made no assumptions, what is posted is a ruby hash with symbol keys. You inferred is that this is JSON and while your inference is likely correct it is not what was posted in the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky: but you did assume, though. Note how the question doesn't say "this is a ruby hash I get after parsing the response as json". Given that the post is tagged with `[ruby]`, it is a valid assumption, but an assumption nonetheless. Anyhow, this leads nowhere, so I'll stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) does what it says, it digs into the hash for a single value, the values you send it, `data->name` is the road the method takes into the hash so to speak.

You can combine this with the [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-slice) method and the [safe navigation operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/).

```rb
response.dig("data")&.slice("name", "placeofbirth")
# => { "name": "joe", "placeofbirth": "canada" }
```

There is no reason to use [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) if you are only going one level deep tho, so instead you can simply use

```rb
response["data"]&.slice("name", "placeofbirth")
# => { "name": "joe", "placeofbirth": "canada" }
```